# Using instr to find 3 matching cell values from a source table row appearing in another table row

Tags: excel, search, vba

I am very new to coding with it, and what appears below probably looks quite horrible.

What this code currently does is do an instr search for all 3 required values appearing in a single, and absolutely defined (for test purposes), row of another table, in a separate worksheet. Copies the A cell value from that row, pastes it into the cell next to the source table row, currently being searched, and colour codes it with a green fill.

What I *want* it to do, is be aware that there is a whole other table of data in the other worksheet, and have it search row by row for all 3 required values matching in a given row.

Once it gets an exact hit, I want it to output the A cell value for the row that has been confirmed to be a match of all 3 required values.

The table in the other sheet is dynamic, in that it increases or decreases in total number of rows day be day.

Is anyone kind enough to be able to help me with this?

Now, here is my novice mishmash of code:

```
Private Sub Match_Click()
Dim i As Integer, row As Integer, narrative1 As String, transDate As Date, 
amount As Double, result As String
row = 2
i = 1
narrative1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row)
transDate = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row)
amount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J" & row)


Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

If narrative1 > "" Then
  If InStr(1, UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D22")), UCase(narrative1)) And 
  InStr(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B22"), transDate) And InStr(1, 
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H22"), amount) Then
  result = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
Else
  result = ""
End If
End If

i = i + 1

If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then result = ""
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & row).Value = result

If result <> "" Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & row).Interior.Color = 
RGB(198, 224, 180)

If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then 
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

row = row + 1
narrative1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & row)
transDate = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row)
amount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J" & row)
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to use `UCase` inside `Instr`

Comment: Using Instr on dates is really ugly and unreliable...I'll try to come up with something. Is the column containing the values in the data sheet consistent? Also, are the three values you're looking for always the same?

Comment: Each new row on the search from table has a new set of dates, amounts and Narrative text. It is going through line by line a csv bank statement file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code will do what you expect, I've commented it to let you know what its doing (I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure it will do the job):

```
Private Sub Match_Click()
Dim i As Long 'These should be Long instead of Integer, as Excel has more cells than Integer has values.
Dim row As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim narrative1 As String
Dim transDate As String
Dim amount As Double
Dim result As String
Dim val1 As Integer
Dim val2 As Integer
Dim val3 As Integer

LastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'get the lastrow of Sheet2
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'get the lastrow of Sheet1

For i = 1 To LastRow2 'loop from row 1 to last on Sheet2
narrative1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & i) 'get the variables to compare
transDate = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i)
amount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J" & i)
    For x = 1 To LastRow ' loop through row 1 to last on Sheet1
        If narrative1 <> "" Then
            val1 = InStr(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Value, narrative1) 'number 4 represents column D
            val2 = InStr(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value, transDate) 'number 2 represents column B
            val3 = InStr(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 8).Value, amount) 'number 8 represents column H

            If val1 > 0 And val2 > 0 And val3 > 0 Then 'if all three have been found
                result = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value 'get result
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & LastRow2 + 1).Value = result 'paster result into next free row on Sheet2 column K
                If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1).Value <> "" Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & LastRow2 + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Else
                result = ""
            End If
        End If
     Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! 

It looks very promising as far as my limited understanding goes.  

Will test it tomorrow and report back.  

Thanks again :-)

Comment: Hmm... Compile error:

Invalid Next control variable reference. At line Next i.

Comment: Needed Next x. Didn't quite work as originally coded, as result has gone to bottom of the table instead of one the same row as the search values. Will tweak to see if I can get it running properly.

Comment: Only saw your Next x answer now. sorry for the redundant comment.

Comment: @JohnnyKelly, let me know how you get on, if it doesn't work as intended, would you be able to share a sample spreadsheet so I can have a look at the layout and then update my answer?

Comment: I just had to tweak the position of the result print to be                 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K" & i).Value = result

Comment: Oh ok,... so if this has helped you, could you mark my response as an answer? Thanks :)

Comment: It runs as expected, and prints matches in the correct position now, the only 'issue' if you can call it that is the speed of doing the work. The table it is searching through in sheet 1 is 50,000 lines long at present. Makes for some waiting time, but certainly not anywhere near as much time as doing it manually(!)

Comment: @JohnnyKelly, it will take a while, as the code is in essence looking at things one row at a time and doing the comparisons against the full list on the other sheet,...so I guess that's just the way the cookie crumbles,... but if you find anything to make it faster, please do let me know too! :)

Comment: Shall do, and thank you very much for the assistance! :-)

Comment: I get the feeling that somehow setting up a dictionary of the data being searched would speed up the code. No idea how to do it though.

Comment: @JohnnyKelly I've got little experience using Data Dictionaries, but as you still have to do comparisons from one row against a full Sheet and then move to the next row, I doubt it would help, similar to using an Array I guess.